# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.Credential.getId()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, capacitor

I am developing a custom plugin in Capacitor 3 and Ionic 6 which retrieves the user's phone number with the help of HintRequest class.

I have added a blank activity (TestActivity) in my number-plugin project
My directory looks like this -

[image]

This is my code inside the TestActivity to invoke the phone number prompt

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        requestHint();
    }
    private void requestHint() {
        HintRequest hintRequest = new HintRequest.Builder()
                .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
                .build();
        PendingIntent intent = Credentials.getClient(this).getHintPickerIntent(hintRequest);
        IntentSenderRequest.Builder intentSenderRequest = new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intent.getIntentSender());
        hintLauncher.launch(intentSenderRequest.build());
    }
    ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> hintLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
            result -> {
                if(result!=null && result.getData()!=null){
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    Credential credential = data.getParcelableExtra(Credential.EXTRA_KEY);
                    String phoneNum = credential.getId();
                    if (phoneNum.contains("+91"))
                        phoneNum = phoneNum.replace("+91", "");
                    Log.d("number 1", "mobile1 "+ phoneNum);
                }
            });
}
```

This is my calling method which is inside the NumberPluginPlugin class

```
private Context context;

    @PluginMethod
    public void getNumber(PluginCall call) {
        if (getPermissionState("number") != PermissionState.GRANTED) {
            requestPermissionForAlias("number", call, "numberPermsCallback");
        } else {
           context = getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(context, TestActivity.class);
            ((Activity) context).startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

When I run the app the TestActivity shows up with a pop up but the app crashes instantly when this error log

**Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=829015426, result=1002, data=Intent {  }} to activity {com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.TestActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.auth.api.credentials.Credential.getId()' on a null object reference**

What am I doing wrong here?
First I thought this might have something to do with the context so I tried to explicitly pass the context casted as an Activity, a workaround which I found online but I am not able to figure out what exactly is causing this error.

**UPDATE**!
I tried to run the app on my device and it runs fine. I see the number pop up. I don't know for some reason this is not working on the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the code was working fine on a real device but wasn't working on the emulator as it didn't have any google account signed in to authenticate.
Once I signed in with my google account on my emulator, I got a number prompt.